# Unity Play Games can't authenticate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have a issue with play games services and unity.
I've done everything by the documentation. I'm a tester, testing is allowed and I've changed the sha1 in api console to the one used by the app. I'm using code from the docs and examples so here is a brief:

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration conf = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(conf);
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

Debug.Log("Authenticating...");
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
{
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Welcome " + Social.localUser.userName);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Authentication failed.");
    }
});
```

When I build the app in development mode the Play Games popup appears, starts loading and disappears and gives me a Authentication failed message. But when I build the app without the development mode nothing happens and I get the authentication failed message instantly. And yes I'm the correct sha1 key.

Please help me

Comment: Did you get it to work? I don't think publishing it has any effect as long as you have testing setup correctly. Here is a note they give you after publishing: "Unpublishing makes the Google Play game services unavailable for your customers. Google Play game services will still be available for testing." One thing I have found that might affect this is the `Anti-Piracy` under linked apps in the Game Services console. I have tried turning this off but so far not successful. It is hard to troubleshoot when uncertain on how long it takes for these changes to be made.

Comment: I say this all assuming you double checked your certificates are matched in the understand the differences between the "upload certificate" and the "app signing certificate". Those seem to be the main causes for this problem, but not in my case. Maybe I just need to wait, please let me know if you got it working.. maybe I have a different issue.

Comment: Update: It's still not working even tho I have a app for the play store certificate and development certificate. None of them are working
https://i.imgur.com/pQZCQfX.png

Comment: I notice is has the `Development` tag next to your app name, mine does not. TBH I am unsure what it means, did you upload a development build to the Play Console? (AFAIK that is not possible but not totally sure). Is your app in an internal test track?

Comment: I've linked the app twice. Once with the app signing certificate set to be default for all users and other one for development.

Answer (score 3):

I did a number of things and finally got it to work. I cannot be sure if they all contributed to solving this issue so here I will list what I did, from greatest to least of my guess of their relevance:

1. Match the SHA-1 certificates. If you are using an app downloaded from Play Store use the "app signing certificate", else use the upload certificate. These are found in the Play Console under YourApp/Release Management/App Signing. As a note, if you are building from Unity directly to your device, you should make sure that you are building with the same key used to upload to Google Play. More info [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1805)
2. If you are using a custom config and are requesting things such             `.RequestServerAuthCode(false)`, you must create an additional ***Web App***. Go to your console project, and under `create credentials` choose `OAuth client ID`, and then select `Web App`.
3. If using internal testing, make sure to authorize accounts in the Play Console under Game Services/Your App/Testing.
4. Try disabling Anti-Piracy in the Play Console under Game Services/Your App/Linked Apps/Your App. Only do this if you are testing app outside Google Play. I think if you are logging in using verified test accounts this doesn't matter.

Edit: Publishing Game Services is required even for testing.. at least that seemed to be the case for me to get it working.

5. Try clearing the cache of your App on your device, I ran into this problem again and this solved it for me.

I finally think I have got it fixed for good.. after nearly a month later. :o Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using
`PlayGamesClientConfiguration conf = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(conf);
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();`
and I've done everything you said before and it's still not working.
https://imgur.com/a/jfclWG5

Comment: I was messing around with it again and it stopped working :(. I'll let you know if I manage to fix it again.. maybe this time  I can pinpoint the solution. Please let me know if you find a fix also.

Comment: Okay I got it working again. It turns out publishing your Game Services is required even for testing.. at least that seems to be the case. If you already have it published and it is still not working, the only other thing I can suggest is to triple check you have your certificates matched; since that seems to be the problem with most people.

Comment: I've checked and they match

Comment: Can someone help me? It's still not working. I'm considering removing the whole app from google play and doing everything again.

Answer (score 0):

Google Services can be published/unpublished separately from your app.
Check if they are correctly published doing the following:

1. Google Play Console
2. Game services
3. Select your game
4. Publishing

Check if Game Services are published.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I feel so ashamed. I thought that testing will mean that I can test the app without publishing it but I was wrong. Thanks

Comment: You can. You just need to publish it on an Internal Track (either "Open Beta" or "Closed Alpha"). Even if you publish the app for internal use, I think you still need to publish the "Game Services" separately to be able to login, use Leaderboards, etc.

Comment: Weird. I did publish the game services 7 hours ago and it's still not working